# Oracle Connect BY return top level only

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get the top most parent of a record using connect by

```
Select distinct parent_box_id,box_id, 
LEVEL,
SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(box_id, '>') "lineage"

  FROM box_lineage lineage 
  where lineage.position = 1 
        START WITH   box_id='00112233   '
   CONNECT BY   box_id = PRIOR parent_box_id
      ORDER SIBLINGS BY box_id;
```

result

```
    parent child level hierarchy
    123456  789456  3   >00112233>963258>789456
    789456  963258  2   >00112233>963258
    963258  00112233    1   >00112233
```

What I want is only `123456  789456  3   >00112233>963258>789456`

I don't know what the top level is it could be 2,3,4 5, 6

I tried `and level >=3` and `level 1` but I only get the bottom level

I've read the other answers on here but none worked

Comment: Several questions... Why select **distinct**, do you expect the same path to be duplicated? Then, if you just want one row to come back, with the path from your box_id to the top, why do you need an ORDER SIBLINGS BY clause? Finally, in the query you use the column alias "lineage" but in the required result you show "hierarchy" and the same with parent_box_id (in the result you show just "parent") etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `AND CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1` to the where clause.

Answer (score 3):

Just to illustrate John Ashley's correct answer, here is a similar query against the EMPLOYEES table in the HR schema (which exists in pretty much all Oracle installations).

**Note** - all the credit should go to John Ashley, here I am just illustrating his solution.

```
select employee_id, manager_id, level, sys_connect_by_path(employee_id, '?') as path
from employees
where connect_by_isleaf = 1
start with employee_id = 116
connect by prior manager_id = employee_id
;

EMPLOYEE_ID MANAGER_ID      LEVEL PATH
----------- ---------- ---------- ---------------
        100                     3 ?116?114?100
```

(Note: in the EMPLOYEES table in HR, the "top" is NULL, the MANAGER_ID for the CEO of the company - this is why the "parent" column shows NULL.)

Answer (score 1):

try using level

```
Select distinct parent_box_id,box_id, 
LEVEL,
SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(box_id, '>') "lineage"

  FROM box_lineage lineage 
  where lineage.position = 1 
  and level = 3
  CONNECT BY   box_id = PRIOR parent_box_id
  START WITH   box_id ='00112233   '
  ORDER SIBLINGS BY box_id;
```

..for max  try this

```
  Select distinct parent_box_id,box_id, 
  LEVEL,
  SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(box_id, '>') "lineage"

  FROM box_lineage lineage 
  where lineage.position = 1 
  and level =  (   

      Select max( LEVEL) 
      FROM box_lineage lineage 
      where lineage.position = 1
      CONNECT BY   box_id = PRIOR parent_box_id
      START WITH   box_id ='00112233   '

  )
  CONNECT BY   box_id = PRIOR parent_box_id
  START WITH   box_id ='00112233   '
  ORDER SIBLINGS BY box_id;
```

Comment: That returns nothing. Is the And with the start with? If I move it to the where clause I get the last row in the result set above 963258  00112233    1   >00112233

Comment: I have slightly update the query .. eventually try select level (removing the and level=1 ) for check what is the proper level (I thought was 1)

Comment: level = 3 works, is there a way to get the max level? It could be 4, 5 or 6 etc

Comment: I have update the answer .. hope is useful ..let me know

Comment: This works if you remove the comma after your subquery select. I wonder if there is a better way without subqueries and using group by...

Comment: The comma is clear  and  i have removed but group by  .. there only a column is subselect .. so  in this case normally don't need the group by  .. let me know .. where you applied group by ..

Comment: Why so complicated when clearly the correct answer is to use CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF, as suggested in the other answer?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly, here is what I did:

Using the common employees example this will do it:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  ( SELECT DISTINCT lowest_employee_id as employee_id,
    manager_id,
    l AS path_level,
    path,
    rank() over (partition BY lowest_employee_id order by l DESC) rnk
  FROM
    (
SELECT employee_id ,
      manager_id,
      level l,
      -- the following line is just for visualization purpose
      SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(manager_id, ' > ') path,
      connect_by_root(employee_id ) lowest_employee_id
    from employees
    start with employee_id = 116
    connect by prior manager_id = employee_id
    )
  )
WHERE rnk = 1
```

Explanation:

`connect_by_root`  will store the starting root for every level, then we rank the levels by its level number and then we filter for only the latest